# Is is safe to hardcode collection names or document ids of Firestore in an Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection "posts" in my Firestore database. To get the documents from this collection, the `get()` method can be used such as `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("posts").limit(10).get();`. Now if someone somehow reverse engineers my app even after encrypting and using proguard and finds out the collection name "posts", can that person run the command `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("posts").get();` to get all the documents at once from his side without any limits? This could be a potential threat as this could slow down services for other users and increase Firestore costs significantly, something similar to DoS attack even if Firestore rules are set such that only logged in users can access the collection "posts". Is there a way to prevent such kinds of attacks?

Answer (score 1):

If your client code queries Firestore at all, it's not possible to fully hide the names of the collections and documents you're working with.  Once a string becomes available in a client app, it's essentially public information.

Developers are expected to use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to determine who can read and write which collection and documents.  Since they are evaluated on the server, they cannot be bypassed from client code.  It's up to you to implement security rules that correctly limit access in the way that your app requires.

Firestore is a cloud service managed by Google, and it will detect some forms of abusive behavior.  You do not have to worry about managing the load on the system - it scales massively.

You should also know that any time you start offering data through public APIs, there is always going to be a chance that someone will try to abuse the system. This is an issue for all cloud-based services.  If you suspect abusive behavior in your project, [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).